# Get tag name of the first question by using regex

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I got a Problem with the following regex pattern:

```
m).*?^([^n]*)(modified)([^n]*)$.*
```

I want to replace the clipboard with

`Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "m).*?^([^n]*)(modified)([^n]*)$.*" ,"" )`

Source looks like:

```
Ask Question    Interesting    326 Featured
Hot     Week     Month    1     vote    0    answers    12    views
Type Guard for empty object
typescript modified 2 mins ago kremerd 312
0    votes
```

Expected result should be:

```
typescript modified 2 mins ago kremerd 312
```

But its replacing nothing. If this works i want to get later the tagnames `^([^n]*)` by using regExMatch.

I am scripting with autohotkey (a windows open souce) from https://autohotkey.com

Comment: It seems to me you wanted to match non-newlines with `[^\n]` (not `[^n]`). Also, you need to make `.` match newlines by adding the `s` modifier. Try `sm).*?^([^\n]*modified[^\n]*)$.*`

Comment: Also, it seems to me you just need `FoundPos := RegExMatch(Clipboard, ".*modified.*", res) ;`  and grab the line value via `res[0]`.

Comment: Try `^(.+)modified(.+)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i want to get the first line. therfore i using yours little modified: `FoundPos := RegExMatch(Clipboard, ".*?(modified).*", res) ; MsgBox,% res[0] " =  res[0]"` But i got now result. its empty hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match a line that contains a `modified` substring. The dot in a regex does not match the newline by default, so you need to pass the `s` (DOTALL) modifier (you may add it together with `m`, MULTILINE, modifier that makes `^` match the start of string position and `$` to match the end of line position). Besides, to match non-newlines you need `[^\n]` (not `[^n]`).

To solve the issue you may use

```
RegExMatch(Clipboard, "s)^.*?(\n[^\n]*)(modified|asked|answered)", res)
```

Grab the whole line value via `res`, the text before the keywords via `res1` and the keyword itself with `res2`.

**Details**

- `s)`  - the `.` now matches any char including line break chars
- `^` - start of the string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(\n[^\n]*)` - Group 1 (accessed via `res1` later): a newline followed with 0+ chars other than newline chars
- `(modified|asked|answered)`  - any of the three alternatives: `modified`, `asked` or `answered`.

Comment: i want to get the first line. therfore i using yours little modified: .*?(modified).* But i got now result. its empty hmm

Comment: @SL5net Did you check `res` value?

Comment: the syntax my IDE is suggestiong is : `RegExMatch(Haystack, NeedleRegEx [, UnquotedOutputVar = "", StartingPos = 1])` UnquotedOutputVar is a string? Not a number?

Comment: `UnquotedOutputVar` is a variable that will hold the regex match. The first item will be the match value, the `x[1]` will hold the first captured value (if there is a capturing group in the regex), and so on.

Comment: actually i try `FoundPos := RegExMatch(Clipboard, ".*?(\n[^\n]*)(modified|asked|answered).*", res) ;
MsgBox,% res[0] " =  res[0]`n , " res[1] " =  res[1] `n" Clipboard " =  Clipboard `n"` but got now result

Comment: @SL5net Ah, you mean you need the text on the line containing `modified` or `asked` or `answered` before this word, right? Then, you may just use `RegExMatch(Clipboard, "(.*?)(modified|asked|answered).*", res)` and then grab the captures via `res[1]` and `res[2]`. Not sure you even need the `.*` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: i want get the tag names of https://stackoverflow.com/ of the first question. therefore you need to use `.*?` ? for set it not greedy

Comment: now i got it: https://imgur.com/a/zobCxVj used: `m)^[.\s\S]*?(\n[^\n]*)(modified|asked|answered)` for some reason `m)^.*?(\n[^\n]*)(modified|asked|answered)` gives empty result

Comment: Do not use `[\s\S]`, you may use `.` and the `s` modifier, `[\s\S]` is a workaround construct matching any char. So, `sm)^.*?(\n[^\n]*)(modified|asked|answered)` will work the same.

Comment: as i sayd . not workd, but the \s\S workaround worked. may with the s) i will try BTW the result is in **res1** not in res[1]

Comment: @SL5net The `s` modifier is the PCRE flag that modifies the behavior of `.`. I updated the answer as per your feedback.

Comment: may you want insert my last version and i check you anser as correct `s)^.*?\n([^\n]*)(modified|asked|answered)` its without m)

Comment: @SL5net Done, I also added the pattern explanation.

Comment: an may us `s` not `sm` . you probably forget ;)

Comment: @SL5net I removed the first solution.